# How to get factor value names from factor operators when writing new estimation commands?

Tags: stata

Stata has some swell built-in operators to facilitate working with factor variables and interactions in the context of estimation commands. For example, assuming there are two factor variables named `sex` (male/female), and `arm` (treat/control) the following command:

```
. regress outcome sex##arm
```

produces estimates for indicator variables thus in the output:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     ln_wage |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
         sex | 
     female  | ...
             | 
         arm |  
    control  | ...
             |
     sex#arm |
femal#contr  | ...
             |
       _cons | ...
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The `##` operator will also work for three-way interactions like `sex##arm##group`. In addition the `ib` or synonymous `b` operator provides a means of specifying which base value of each factor variable will serve as the referent category.

If I am writing a new estimation command `MyReg`, is there some syntax or parsing tool that will permit a call like `MyReg outcome sex##arm` to get access to these factor names/factor value names (appearing the left column of the above table) without having to write my own parser for the nontrivial set of Stata's factor variable operators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not entirely sure if I completely understood what you have in mind, but here's an example to get you going down this road:

```
/* (1) Define MyReg */
capture program drop MyReg

program define MyReg, eclass
    version 14.2
    syntax varlist(min=1 fv)

    /* do the regression */ 
    regress `varlist'

    /* pull out the column names from the coefficient matrix */ 
    local fvnames : colfullnames e(b)

    /* drop omitted categories from column names list */ 
    foreach var of local fvnames {
            _ms_parse_parts `var'
            if !`r(omit)' {
                local fvlist `fvlist' `var'
            }   
        }

    /* e-return the names */    
    ereturn local fvlist `fvlist'

end;

/* (2) An Example */
sysuse auto
MyReg price i.foreign##c.weight
display "Left Column Contents: " e(fvlist)
```

There's also a great FAQ on useful factor variable commands for programmers [here](https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/programming/factor-variable-support/).

Comment: +1 Thank you! That is as near perfect as I can get the rest of the way myself. (The "rest of the way" simply being a lookup of the factor value labels corresponding to the numeric prefix in what's returned in e(fvlist) :). And thank you for the FAQ link.

Comment: You might want to look at what estout does for that and replicate it.